# How to move a pixel column in PyQt5 Pixmap?

Tags: python, pyqt, pixmap

I am making a python project,I am using pyqt. The aim is to show a picture (I am using Pixmap) and I want that any column of pixel of this picture go down randomly according to the time. The aim is to create an effect of 'dissolve' the screen.

Here is my code :

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# ---------- Imports ----------

import sys, time, os, random
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

# ---------- Main ----------

class Ui (QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        # ----- Fichiers -----

        folder_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        self.picture_path = str(folder_path + '\\solar_wallpaper.jpg')
        self.icon_path = str(folder_path + '\\solar_icon.ico')

        # ----- Configuration de la fenêtre -----

        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() &~ Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() &~ Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() &~ Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint)
        self.setWindowTitle('Solar')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(self.icon_path))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;")

        # ----- Appel des méthodes -----

        self.init_components()
        self.init_layout()
        self.showFullScreen()

    def init_components (self):

        self.setCentralWidget(QGroupBox())
        self.picture = QLabel(self)
        self.picture.setScaledContents(True)
        self.picture.setPixmap(QPixmap(self.picture_path))
        self.picture.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        colonne = self.picture.width()
        for i in range (colonne):
            None

    def init_layout (self):

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.picture)
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.layout)

# ---------- Launcher ----------

app = QApplication.instance()
if not app :
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ui = Ui()
app.exec()
```

Comment: What do you mean by *go down randomly according to the time*? Could you put an image (maybe a gif) of what you want to get?

Comment: I would like something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/OppSt.png

Comment: That image does not help to understand, maybe several images will help, for example place the original image and show other images where the process has been applied to the columns

Comment: I think an old virus called Twith Booster show the effect I want. I would like the same effect on the screen with pyqt. Here is a link of what the virus do on the screen in background https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RW2u3adF2yI
Here you can see the screen is 'melting'

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to copy and paste pieces of rectangles but with a vertical distance:

```py
import random
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPainter, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel

COLUMN_WIDTH = 10
DELTA = 10


def build_pixmap():
    delta = 20
    pixmap = QPixmap(512, 512)
    pixmap.fill(QColor("blue"))
    painter = QPainter(pixmap)
    for i in range(5, 15):
        dt = i * delta
        r = QRect(pixmap.rect().adjusted(0, dt, 0, -dt))
        color = QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3))
        painter.fillRect(r, color)
    painter.end()
    return pixmap


def aply_effect(pixmap, number_of_columns):
    i = round(pixmap.width() / COLUMN_WIDTH)
    for _ in range(number_of_columns):
        j = random.randint(0, i)
        rect = QRect(j * COLUMN_WIDTH, 0, COLUMN_WIDTH, pixmap.height())

        pix = pixmap.copy(rect)
        painter = QPainter(pixmap)
        painter.drawPixmap(rect.translated(0, DELTA), pix)
    painter.end()
    return pixmap


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    pixmap_demo = build_pixmap()
    label = QLabel(pixmap=pixmap_demo)
    label.show()

    def on_timeout():
        out_pixmap = aply_effect(label.pixmap(), 40)
        label.setPixmap(out_pixmap)

    timer = QTimer(interval=40, timeout=on_timeout)
    timer.start()

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is typically what I want :) I will work on it and come back :)